# Правильный редирект на мобильную версию сайта

Tags: redirect, mobile

Нужно сделать правильный редирект на мобильную версию сайта, если я планирую сделать её в виде `m.xxx.yyy`, если ширина экрана `<850px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете Apache, то пропишите в файле .htaccess следующее:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.yyy$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.xxx.yyy/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если вам требуется редиректить пользователя при определенной ширине экрана, то определяйте ее в JS при загрузке страницы и если она меньше определенного значения, то делаете редирект:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (window.screen.availWidth < 850)
        window.location = window.location.href.replace('://', '://m.');
});
```

Если требуется выставить редирект по ширине окна (с учетом zoom браузера), то вместо `window.screen.availWidth` используем `window.innerWidth`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 850)
        window.location = window.location.href.replace('://', '://m.');
});
```

Но лучше использовать media-queries, чем выносить отдельную версию на поддомен. Будет куда проще в поддержке. В случае необходимости можно переписать некоторые JS-функции под  вывод контента для мобильного экрана.

Comment: Да, но я забыл дописать..что нужно при определенной ширине экрана

Comment: innerWidth возвращает не ширину экрана, а ширину видимой области, которая может оказаться как меньше, так и больше ширины экрана

Comment: @andreymal поправил код

Comment: За редирект в ресайзе надо руки отрывать.

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил код

Comment: Но это всё равно не размер экрана, а размер окна...

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил в соответствии с запросом задачи автора

Comment: @Qwertiy но по мне лучше media-queries, чем верстать отдельную версию под мобильные экраны.

Comment: А зачем `DOMContentLoaded` нужен?

Comment: @Qwertiy это опционально, можно и без него

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.screen.availWidth < 850) {
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('://', '://m.')
}
```